# side by side div - left div is not positioned correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put two divs side by side using the following code. Basically it works as you can see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/G7nRckdQkkkopRvqwGpc?p=preview):

```
  div.keep-row-together {
      overflow-x: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
  }
  div.keep-row-together [class*="span"] {
      display: inline-block;
      float: none; /* - disabled as having issue in firefox */
  }
```

But when I put a js grid into the right div the left div moves down (at least in Chrome and Firefox). Any idea what I have to change? Here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iDW8yErlxilOINQAVgKi?p=preview).

Comment: `display: table-cell;` would work, but I dont think it is the correct way to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add to your divs

```
vertical-align: bottom;
```

Comment: Check this post for explanation: http://blog.mikepearce.net/2010/10/08/the-curious-case-of-inline-block-min-height-and-vertical-align/ and mark this as answered if you are satisfied.

Comment: hum.. ok. do not really get it. but it works. thanks man, saved my weekend!

Comment: by default **inline-blocks** tend to float to the top. By setting vertical alignment to bottom, they drop down. They drop down on the line they are on (and not to the bottom of the page), because **inline-block** elements are *block* elements that behave like *inline* elements.

Comment: hmm.. stupidly when adding vertical-align: bottom; the divs are not anymore placed side-by-side when shrinking the page. the divs should always stay side by side. sorry I did not mention this in my question.

Comment: here is the plnkr: http://run.plnkr.co/ihbqwOaXc8Uqw02s/ ..and it works. sorry, just realized I had another issue in my local dev. environment. thanks!